# SASS prefix custom element

Tags: sass, prefix

I try to prefix a custom element that looks like this `<myprefix-toggle></myprefix-toggle>`. It does not work. However if I add `#` as if it would be an id it does compile. Why and how can I get around it?

**Works**

```
$prefix: "myprefix-";

#{$prefix}toggle {
  background: red;
}
```

**Does not work**

```
$prefix: "myprefix-";

{$prefix}toggle {
  background: red;
}
```

The error I get is probably not that related to the real issue...

> Error: expected ':' after $prefix in assignment statement

If it's of importance I use [gulp-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass) to compile the sass to css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hashtag and the curly brackets is the Sass syntax for interpolation `#{ ... }`

```
$prefix: "myprefix-";

                            //  CSS output 
#{$prefix}toggle  { ... }   //  myprefix-toggle { ... }
.#{$prefix}toggle { ... }   // .myprefix-toggle { ... }
##{$prefix}toggle { ... }   // #myprefix-toggle { ... }
```